# Using :after pseudoelement with :required pseudoclass

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Pardon me if this question is already answered, but I couldn't find it.

I am trying to put an asterisk after all `<input required>` elements.

I found that I can style these with the `:required` selector.

I would like to use the `:after` pseudoelement to add an asterisk.

My CSS:

```
*:required:after {
    content:"*";
    font-size:48px;
    color:red;
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
}
```

In Opera 30 and Chrome 40, I see this (note that nearly all of these have the `required` attribute, see code below.):

[image: A Pseudoclass's Pseudoelement]

In Firefox 39, IE 11, and Edge no pseudoelements are displayed.
Why is it that the pseudoelement only displays on the `<input type="date"/>` and not on any of the other inputs or selects? And, more importantly, how can I make it display on all `required` elements?

I'm using bootstrap3 and jquery, if that matters.

HTML:

```
<label>Title 
    <select name="title" id="title" class="form-control" required> <!-- Trigger Gender here I think... -->
        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
        <option value="Rev.">Rev.</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label>First Name (as on Passport)  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Charles" class="form-control" required/></label>
<label>Last Name (as on Passport)   <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Studd" class="form-control" required/></label>
<label>Maiden Name (if applicable)  <input type="text" name="maidenName" id="maidenName" class="form-control"/></label>
<label>Other Names                  <textarea name="aliases" id="aliases" placeholder="C. T. Studd" class="form-control"></textarea></label>
<label>Date of Birth                <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" class="form-control" placeholder="12/02/1860" required/></label>
<label>Gender Autofilled
    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Note that the spec says: [`Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html) So this is not invalid behavior.

Comment: This may be outside of your spec; however, what about putting a red/"alert" border around required elements?  This way, the selector `input:required:invalid` can be used.  You will still indicate what fields are required without using extra markup.  http://jsfiddle.net/c44pouh4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the spec does not define behavior of pseudoelements with replaced elements, so this is not required to be consistent across browsers or even within browsers apparently.

The reason is that insertion using `content` makes a replaced element, and replaced replaced elements are not yet defined. From MDN, replaced elements are: [`external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS. Typical replaced elements are <img>, <object>, <video> or form elements like <textarea> and <input>. Some elements, like <audio> or <canvas> are replaced elements only in specific cases. Objects inserted using the CSS content properties are anonymous replaced elements.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

Until an indeterminate future draft, the best bet is either to use the `*:required+:after` selector with an empty span (or whatever) or use `:required` pseudoclass with something that can be used with a replaced element, like a `background-image`.

We can hope that the current behavior of -webkit- in replacing `content:''` after `type='date'` points toward allowing pseudoelements on all elements. We'll see.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-elements don't work on `input`s, because `input`s are empty elements. You'll have to put an element after each input, then use the `:required` pseudo-class and the `+` combinator to style that.

Comment: Yet, see the screenshot. Are you saying that this is non-spec behavior?

Comment: My apologies, I was confused what you meant about that, but I just tested it out and it does indeed display the pseudo-element for the date input.  Interesting.

Comment: No browser *should* support pseudo-elements on `input` elements but some do...and yes, it's non-spec behaviour in that respect.

Comment: Do you have a link to the spec that says it shouldn't? I can't find it.

Comment: Ah, found one. Apparently it's ok according to the spec, but not required: `Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.` http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html

Comment: Plus one for the +. That looks like the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

`:after` or `:before` doesn't work on `input` or `img` elements. It can be used on container elements e.g. `<div></div>`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)

In your case  I suggest you make use of `label` instead of `input` elements. Add a class for `label` elements which has a required input inside. Of course this would need a bit more of work since you have to set the positions correctly.

e.g.

```
<label class="required-container">
  First Name (as on Passport)  
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Charles" class="form-control" required/>
</label>
```

Your css:

```
label.required-container:after {
    content:"*";
    font-size:48px;
    color:red;
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
}
```

Comment: Disagree. See screenshot and spec link edited into answer.

Comment: @Josiah So I should have said in most it doesn't work. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/987447), it has a good explanation regarding the W3C specification.

Comment: @Josiah I think that specification you note on your post means it doesn't work on `img` elements for now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to influence what is displayed "in the" input based on one of the input's attributes is to simply place a `span` or any other suitable element after the input.  Then, it is just simple linking via adjacent selector.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvzjf002/.

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type = "text" required/><span></span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

label > input {
    height: 25px;
    font: normal 14px/25px Sans-Serif;
    padding: 0 25px 0 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    outline: 0;
}

label > input:required + span:before {
    content:"\f069";
    font: normal 14px/1 "Font Awesome";
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 5px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```